# Evernote integration with Salesforce

Tags: managed-package

We want to integrate evernote with salesforce. We have checked the evernote package on appexchange, but we are not able to define rules for associating specific notes to specific account or leads. Let me know if any one with experience on this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have heard of Zapier - it is an API connector tool.  It can pretty much connect anything with anything they have a 'zap' for Evernote business / SF.

https://zapier.com/zapbook/evernote-business/

Might be worth a look. Although I don't know if it would work for you specific requirements.